# Open Cart 3x - Вывод изображения

Tags: opencart, twig, opencart3.x

коллеги!

Ранее не сталкивался с opencart/twig.
Задача: создать тему на основании вёрстки.
На входе: вся вёрстка есть

Вопрос:
Как вывести изображение в шаблон? Т.е. есть иконка в шапке сайта в виде изображения, и её надо вывести во фронт.

Абсолютный путь не подходит, относительный не срабатывает. Предполагаю что надо использовать какой-то встроенный метод opencart'a для сборки корректного относительного пути.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, разобрался:

- В корне проекта есть файл config с глобальными переменными, нас интересует HTTP_SERVER / HTTPS_SERVER
- Идём в файл контроллера нашей вьюхи, определяем новую переменную, указав ей в качестве значения HTTP_SERVER + путь до директории со служебными изображениями
- Во вьюхе используем объявленную переменную в двойных фигурных скобках {{var_name}} и добавляем само имя целевого подгружаемого изображения